# Why switch button inside viewpager changes state when I hide a view

Tags: android, android-fragments

My code construction is like this:
-->MainActivity

```
MainActivity
    '-> Fragment  
          '-> WebView  
          '-> Button  
          '-> ViewPager
                '-> ChildFragment  
                      '-> SwitchButton
```

The button is used to change the visibility of the WebView view.
My problem is that when the webView visibility is changed to GONE, the state of the SwitchButton inside the viewPager changes to the default state which is OFF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface for communicates from ChildFragment -> Adapter